# for loop working in CMD prompt but not in batch file - for loop was copy pasted

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, vpn

Note: I have almost no idea at all how batch file 'for' loops work.

The batch file I have currently:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -connect
"C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin\HMA! Pro VPN.exe" -changeip  
ping -w 2000 -n 1 1.1.1.1
:wait
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,*" %A in (`netsh interface show interface`) do @if "%D"=="Local Area Connection 2" set state=%B
if %state%==Connected goto :end
goto :wait
:end
```

I'm trying to write a robust IP changer that utilizes HMA! Pro VPN - it should work whether the VPN client has been opened or not, and whether the VPN is currently opened or not, and should pause until the VPN has connected.

If you Google the for loop, you'll see it appear in a stackoverflow answer - this for loop works perfectly fine in a CMD prompt, and sets %state% to Connected/Disconnected well, but in a batch file, throws the following error:

```
D"=="Local was unexpected at this time.
```

I would learn more about for loops in batch had I not been under a very tight schedule - I *have* learnt about these before, but this loop looks pretty weird to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does FOR loop command not work in a batch file which works on Windows command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431109/why-does-for-loop-command-not-work-in-a-batch-file-which-works-on-windows-comman)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a batch file you have to use two percents for `FOR` parameters, that's all

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,*" %%A in (`netsh interface show interface`) do (
    if "%%D"=="Local Area Connection 2" set state=%%B
)
```

Comment: I was always used to using %var%, never got to fully go into the intricacies of % signs in batch. Thanks a lot though, it worked :P