# Why does FOR loop command not work in a batch file which works on Windows command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
FOR /L %A IN (1,1,100) DO echo %A
```

The code above in a batch script results in this error:

> A was unexpected at this time.

The same command line works fine on Windows command prompt.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double percent characters:

```
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,100) DO echo %%A
```

Answer (score 2):

If you run `FOR /?` you'll find that the first paragraph after the parameter list starts as follows:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.

As an example, let's start with a simple `FOR` loop:

```
FOR %x in (*) DO ECHO %x
```

This will run just fine from a command prompt, printing out the name of each file in the current directory, but if we use this verbatim in a Batch file, we'll get an error saying this:

> x was unexpected at this time.

This is because Batch files have some extra abilities that use the percent sign immediately followed by some text, so when `FOR` is called from inside a Batch file it instead looks for two percent signs. So if we want to use that same `FOR` loop in a Batch script, we need to replace each instance of `%x` with `%%x`.

What we end up putting in our Batch file is this:

```
FOR %%x in (*) DO ECHO %%x
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `%`, `%A` is for use on command lines only.

when used in batch files `%A` should be substituted with `%%A`.